# Problem for creating smart contract NFT marketplace

Tags: smart-contracts, nft, fa2

I am trying to make an NFT Marketplace using the tutorials given here: https://tezos.com/developers/tutorials/nft-markeplace

The first problem I had was when they give us the smartcontract, the following address is wrong:

```
FA2 = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://smartpy.io/dev/templates/fa2_lib.py")
```

I corrected the address which is no longer functional by: https://smartpy.io/templates/fa2_lib.py

But an error remains:

```
In /lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py, line 1419:

raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError:
```

The code of my smartcontract is the same as for the smartcontract of the marketplace on the tutorial of the Tezos site.

I do not understand my error given that the code is given, would it come from the Tezos template?

Thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial at https://tezos.com/developers/tutorials/nft-markeplace is using the SmartPy legacy syntax.

You can still use it at https://legacy.smartpy.io/ide. You also need to update the URL from which the template is loaded:

```
FA2 = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://legacy.smartpy.io/templates/fa2_lib.py")
```

Here is a link to the complete example: https://legacy.smartpy.io/ide?code=eJxtksluwjAQhu95CiunQFFQc0AVUqRSifQCCNSqPVqD44DBS2pPCvTp6yyUgvDBGnu@2X5bqNJYJE6BxfJEwBFXBkE2SUjqrViYWDQEdcyKEmlhjaKVlVG4RSzdeDiUfAPsFHcZfMQQuSolIHfDAhIqxTouT2EvCJgE58i72XMd@QrxJFdCD0htzoXGRYHtIYPE271xQPzKeUEoFVogpZHjshgQaOP6_f0B7MZ1YL0u0fFNzB98xTYd3KJN@gsXPHsdIM@pHwgjDYp7acKF0SSr9EasJW9H8hPWvTZU15JjXIMVptWy9tDzVdQWaGr9cwNjptIYhY0jbCGv7P4eUzluHzuGS3M3T80kHYN1m5QZjRYYerp9iqZU2uz1nJY7NyCKI@SAkPqMFQrp4vMNNUX7AURZ1O@_Up9Pu@U8f1HZt3ubmtnncrkF87MY7V5X2fG4P1TzGX5kX9PTKFuHvd61NA_pTV_BL3rY1ds-

If you're interested in working with the new syntax and the updated FA2 lib, here is the documentation: https://smartpy.io/guides/FA2-lib/overview